# Screws that are larger than wood itself

Tags: plywood, screws

I have a piece of wood that's about 3cm thick and I'd like to put some screws with hooks on it but I just can't find small screws.

Can I

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it.  It rather looks like you hit "Submit" by accident.

Comment: YES, yes you can. We have faith in you.

Comment: @Graphus Interesting point.  The OP actually says "three **centi**metres", which is quite chunky.  I can't imagine not being able to find hooks will less than that.

Comment: Would cup hooks work? https://www.amazon.com/BronaGrand-100pcs-Nickel-Plated-Ceiling/dp/B0785JK9QK/

Comment: @MartinBonner, thanks for that I obviously hadn't had my coffee before reading this Q!